# Base R check functions and packages - trying to validate base R

Tags: r, validation, radix

I am trying to validate and do basic checks on base R. I want to document that my installation has been done correctly and check that basic functions in R are doing what they meant to do accurately.

I found documentation in R for using "check", "rcmdcehck", "devtools::check". But I have a hard time finding a real full example of how to run the command to do the checks.  I get error messages such as 
 *"Error: No root directory found in C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/tests or its parent directories. Root criterion: contains a file `DESCRIPTION` with contents matching `^Package:"*
I tried and directed my command to the library path and also to "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/tests" directory where there is a number of test files.  The scripts in this "tests" directory are exactly what I need to run. There are many files in that "tests" directory and each one tests different base R packages like arith.R or dateTime.R, and each has a matching output file. I want to find out how to automate running all these .R files and automatically check the results against the matching output file?
As I said, I have tried some variations of commands I stated earlier above.

Could someone point me to a good reference or if you have an example of the command to run these .R scripts that are in "tests" directory and check against the provided outputs in the same directory.

Comment: This is described in the R Installation and Administration manual.  You need to run `make check` or `make check-devel`.  Since you're on Windows, read Chapter 3, in particular 3.1.7 and previous sections.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I did read that section and tried it. I assume I need to run this in System Command. When I did that and run "make check" or "make check-devel", I get the following message    make: *** No rule to make target 'check-devel'.  Stop.  Do I need to specify an option or need to run another program before these commands?

Comment: It sounds as though you didn't build R yourself.  In that case, skip to section 3.2.